# Datatables Data Method

Tags: jquery, sql, ajax, web, datatable

I recently created a Datatable which is pulling data from a .txt file with AJAX. However I am quite new to AJAX, Datatables etc. And I feel like using a .txt file or using internal data is probably not best practice.
I am curious as to which other methods can be used to make this more effective, as this .txt file is going to get quite large, and does not seem to be the optimum way to add date.
I have looked into the use of SQL, but not sure how youd get from having Data within an SQL table, and then adding that to a datatable.

This is not my area of expertise, but I am wanting to expand my skillset.

Code for the script pulling the data from .txt.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#dt_example').DataTable( {

    dom: 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
     "ajax": "objects.txt",
    "columns": [
               {
            "className":      'details-control',
            "orderable":      false,
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "position" },
        { "data": "contractor" },
        { "data": "section" },
        { "data": "project" }
    ],
    "order": [[1, 'asc']],
        } );
```

} );

Comment: How are you serving your webpages?

Comment: You can use ajax to call pages written in php, .net, coldfusion, etc which can get data from databases.

Comment: @DanBracuk currently the web page is created using HTML, CSS and some JS for the datatable. 
A script is set up which pulls the data from the text file, and then populates the table.

Comment: Does your site currently use a database at all?

Comment: @markpsmith it does not. Currently it is just a plain old html website, built with Skel, and displays a datatable within it, populated from the method displayed above.

Comment: I was just trying to ascertain how much work would be involved in integrating a server-side datatable solution. Obviously it would be easier if there were server-side technologies already in place!

Comment: @markpsmith I mean using the .txt file does work, its not a major issue currently. I am just thinking, if I want someone else to add information to the datatable currently the only way is to get them to edit the .txt file and push it to the server directly, which doesnt sound perfect to me.

Comment: Are you doing this for yourself or for an employer? If it's the former then you have nothing to lose, if it's for an employer then I'm guessing it'll come down to cost.